# How to calculate BMI in C++ with ft and inches in calculation

Tags: c++

How do you calculate BMI = mass (lb) x 703/ (height(in))squared in C++.

BMI answer was 33.4695

```
I entered:
cout << "weight(lbs)";
cin >> lbs;
cout << "height";
cin >> height >> in;

BMI = ((lbs) * 703)/pow(height(in)), 2);
```

I'm having and error: no instance of overloaded function "pow" matched the argument list argue types are: (<error-types>).

I have included the `<cmath>` file and height is defined as double.

Comment: If you refine the question to "how to convert centimeters to inches" it becomes easy. Always tackle the cause, not the symptom :)

Comment: The root cause here seems to be a lack of understanding about physical quantities and units. And it's not helped by common programming languages. " Height" really is a physical quantity. A particular height can be expressed as  a number and a unit, say "70 inches"  or the more formal " 1.75 meters". As the example shows, one height can have two numbers associated with it, because the units differ. So the usual convention is that you make an explicit choice for the unit (as is done for lbs here) and then ignore the unit.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start saying you don't need to call pow() at all, but in your case you misplaced the braces. It should be

```
pow(height, 2)
```

Assuming that height is a numeric variable.
It's not clear if you want to include somehow the units of measures of phisical quantities (inches or pound) into your variables. That's a more challenging task, but meanwhile you can use this:

```
float weight = 0, height = 0;
cout << "Enter weight(lbs): ";
cin >> weight;
cout << "Enter height(inches):";
cin >> height;

float BMI = weight * 703.0 / (height * height);
cout << "BMI = " << BMI << '\n';
```